# dotted output after skeletonization in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

I wish to skeletonize this image

[image]

To do so i am using matlab's `bwmorph` function, Here is the snippet :

```
bw = bwmorph(img_bw,'skel',Inf);
```

However the output is not as expected. Here is the output.

[image]

Could someone suggest a better way to achieve proper results ?

**EDIT:** here is a stripped down relevant code

```
img = imread(name);
img = rgb2gray(img*4);
img_bw = img > 50;
img_bw = medfilt2(img_bw,[10 10]);
bw = bwmorph(img_bw,'skel',Inf);
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your result, please put the full code you are using into the question.

Comment: I have edited the question @Daniel

Comment: Tried your code, resulting in this image: http://abload.de/image.php?img=ljkjx9.png

Comment: Do you get any warning like `Warning: Image is too big to fit on
screen; displaying at 25% `?

Comment: wow. That's strange!! I would be happy with that output.

Comment: Yes. I do get that warning

Comment: Then you did not provide us with the original image. The one in your question is scaled down.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. Why should that matter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is aliasing, the `imshow` function can not display the full image because it is to large to fit the screen. To fit the screen some rows and columns are skipped, which cause the lines to be disconnected. To display an image at full resolution using a scrollpanel, use `imscrollpanel`

```
hFig = figure('Toolbar','none', 'Menubar','none');
hIm = imshow(bw);
hSP = imscrollpanel(hFig,hIm);
```

Comment: Oh. Ok. Didn't know about that. Thanks !